# How common is QRM on air band radio?

Tags: radio-communications

How common is it for QRM to interfere with aviation radio, whether from multiple operators transmitting simultaneously, from an unlicensed transmitter, or from sources other than air band radios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience it is primarily “doubling up” where two stations start transmitting at once and step on each other.  This happens quite regularly, in my area it would certainly be a daily occurrence.  It’s generally not a problem.  One of the advantages of AM is that it’s easy for a listening station to tell when two stations have talked simultaneously, whereas the “capture effect” of FM detection makes that harder to discern.

In 30+ years I have very rarely ever encountered other RF interference, (maybe once or twice?) and have never encountered nuisance transmissions.